# Select sql with multiple combinations of criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, cascading-deletes

Please help me to build select SQL and my criteria is

**user**

> user_id      deleted
>   111            1
>   222            0
>   333            1

**tab1**

> user_id      deleted
>   111            1
>   222            0
>   333            0

**tab2**

> user_id      deleted
>   111            1
>   222            0
>   333            1

**tab3**

> user_id      deleted
>   111            1
>   222            1
>   333            0

Situation for me is that if a user_id in user table is deleted (deleted=1) then all its reference records in tab1, tab2 and tab3 should be deleted (deleted=1).

I need to find out user_ids in user table who are deleted (deleted=1) but their records remained active in either tab1, tab2 or tab3 tables (deleted=0)

For example: 
user_id:111 is deleted and its data in all other tables are also deleted. But user_id:333 is deleted but its records in tab1 and tab3 remain active. I need to find out these user_id, like 333.

Please help me to build select sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT 111 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL 
                          SELECT 222 AS user_id, 0 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL
                         SELECT 333 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual ),
         y as (SELECT 111 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL 
                          SELECT 222 AS user_id, 0 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL
                         SELECT 333 AS user_id , 0 AS deleted FROM dual ),
         z as (SELECT 111 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL 
                          SELECT 222 AS user_id, 0 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL
                         SELECT 333 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual ),
         w as (SELECT 111 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL 
                          SELECT 222 AS user_id, 1 AS deleted FROM dual UNION ALL
                         SELECT 333 AS user_id , 1 AS deleted FROM dual )

SELECT x.user_id FROM x, y, z, w 
WHERE x.user_id = y.user_id AND 
      x.user_id = z.user_id AND 
      x.user_id = w.user_id AND 
      x.deleted = 1 AND 
                  (x.deleted != y.deleted OR 
                   x.deleted != z.deleted OR
                   x.deleted != w.deleted);
```

OUTPUT will be:

```
   USER_ID
----------
    333
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response brenners1302. This is indeed helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
   SELECT USER_ID FROM USER AS A
    WHERE DELETED = 1
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TAB1 AS B WHERE A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID AND B.DELETED = 0)
    OR  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TAB2 AS B WHERE A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID AND B.DELETED = 0)
    OR  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TAB3 AS B WHERE A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID AND B.DELETED = 0)
```